# Why Mypy annotations use square brackets

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Mypy uses square brackets to define annotations:

```
from typing import List


def do_nothing() -> List[int]:
    pass
```

Unlike less and greater than (`<int>`), square brackets are actual brackets (`[int]`).
They can't be operators so they auto-close in any proper text editor.

I'd like to know if this is the reason behind that choice or if there are other reasons.

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#which-brackets-for-generic-type-parameters

Comment: @Michael0x2a Thank you, I consider this a valid answer.